# Detecting unique scroll events in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

`$(window).scroll()` lets you detect scroll events.

However, a single scroll triggers it many times.

How can I detect a literal scroll event; ie corresponding to a single swipe or mouse scroll?

Using a time threshold isn't ideal, because if you scroll hard enough, it can trigger up to a couple seconds' worth of scrolling.

Comment: You can't, all you can do is debounce it or count the scrolled amount

Comment: Watch the pointer events https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent

Comment: The right keyword  for your question is `scroll delta`, good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't native events to detect when scrolling starts and stops, but you can achieve it through a plugin like this: https://github.com/ssorallen/jquery-scrollstop

It provides two events, scrollstart and scrollstop.

```
$(window)
  .on("scrollstart", function() {

  })
  .on("scrollstop", function() {

  });
```

It basically fires the scrollstart event after the first scroll then fires the scrollstop event after 250ms of no other scroll events. The time is adjustable.